# JSON not passing array data to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, post

I am trying to change my code to use json on recommendation from a previous question to simplify things a bit...

On client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.tablednd_0_5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.json-2.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table').tableDnD();
    });
    function sendData() {
        data = $('#table').tableDnDSerialize();
        alert(data); // shows expected data
        document.dataform.data.value = $.toJson(data);
        document.data.submit();
    }
</script>

<form action="$php_page_name" method="post" name="dataform" onSubmit="sendData()">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The js alert outputs the expected array, which i think is converted to a string by this point. But when I submit form.data, my php:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
print_r($data);
print_r($_POST);
```

returns only:

> Array ( [data] => )

Any ideas why nothing is being passed ?

Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the return of the function:

```
onSubmit="return sendData()"
```

Otherwise the form will be submitted immediatly and does'nt wait till data is changed.

inside the function replace this

```
document.data.submit();
```

with this:

```
return true;
```

**Furthermore: assuming you use this as jquery.json-2.2.js :

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/downloads/detail?name=jquery.json-2.2.js&can=2&q=

The method-name is

`$.toJSON` instead of `$.toJson`**

Comment: The form is currently only submitted when Submit is clicked not immediately... however I've changed it as per your suggestion, but it made no difference...

Comment: That's what I mean, if the submit-button gets clicked, without the suggested changes the form would'nt wait till the function has manipulated the field. There may be other bugs that prevent the form from submitting the assumed value, but my suggestion is obligatory anyway.

Comment: OK thanks for that then, I've changed it now. Still nothing being received on the php side though...

Answer (score 1):

try not naming to elements the same.
your form is named 'data' and so is your hidden input.

Comment: And shouldn't document.data.data.value = $.toJson(data); be document.data.value = $.toJson(data); ?

Comment: I have changed it to: document.dataform.data.value = $.toJson(data);

Comment: the first data (in document.data.data.value) referred to the form name, so I think that was correct... it was all working like this before trying to implement the JSON stuff...