# jQuery/Ajax PHP POST call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am posting a form with the following:

```
if ( flag ) {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'submit_licence.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'flag=' + flag + '&region=' + jQuery('#licenceRegion').val() + '&lnum=' + jQuery('#enterLicence').val() + '&fname=' + jQuery('#fname').val() + '&lname=' + jQuery('#lname').val(),
    success: function( data ) {

    }
});
}
```

The HTML

```
<input class="buttondb4 white2 large" type="text" value=" " id="enterLicence" />
<input type="hidden" name="licenceRegion" id="licenceRegion" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fname" value="First" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="lname" id="lname" value="Last" />
```

and my PHP:

```
if ($_POST){
$lnum     = noescape($_POST['lnum']);
$fname    = noescape($_POST['fname']);
$lname    = noescape($_POST['lname']);
$region   = noescape($_POST['region']);
$flag     = noescape($_POST['flag']);  

//mysql query here

}
```

But when its posted, it is not retrieving any of the posted data (the posted values are blank)

Why is it not pulling the data? What am I missing? What have I done wrong?

Unfortunately I cannot post the entire script/page due to it being a private project for a client although I think I have provided enough information for what I am trying to do.

Comment: You have not provided any information. The root of the issue seems to be where you actually output the data, and you're not showing that part of the code.

Comment: Check your post request with Firebug/Chrome dev tools

Comment: How do you figure that? The calling of the input fields in other parts of the script work fine, I am only having problems with this specific part, hence me only posting this much information.

Comment: Not sure if this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076686/json-not-passing-array-data-to-php

Comment: The only thing that pops up in Firebug is: The 'charCode' property of a keydown event should not be used. The value is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this on SO

You need to wait for the return of the function:

```
onSubmit="return sendData()"
```

Otherwise the form will be submitted immediatly and does'nt wait till data is changed.

inside the function replace this

```
document.data.submit();
```

with this:

```
return true;
```

Link posted in comment above

Answer (score 2):

jQuery ajax calls fail silently when the json response is malformed.

Make sure that you use this format for json:

```
{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 25}
```

Do not use single quotes.

PHP's [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) does it correctly.

To further debug the error use a `complete(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus)` callback.

The second argument is the error type. (see [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     ...
     if ( flag ) {
         $.ajax({
            url: 'submit_licence.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'flag=' + flag + '&' + $('#someId').serialize(),
            success: function( data ) {

            }
         });
     }
   }); 
</script>
...
<form id='someId'>
  ...
  <input class="buttondb4 white2 large" type="text" value=" " id="enterLicence" />
  <input type="hidden" name="licenceRegion" id="licenceRegion" value="" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fname" value="First" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="lname" id="lname" value="Last" />
</form>
```

checks whether the data has been sent, " print_r($_POST); " , and this should work

```
 //print_r($_POST);
 if ($_POST){
  $lnum     = noescape($_POST['lnum']);
  $fname    = noescape($_POST['fname']);
  $lname    = noescape($_POST['lname']);
  $region   = noescape($_POST['region']);
  $flag     = noescape($_POST['flag']);  

  //mysql query here
  ...
  echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox to inspect the HTTP headers using Ajax and without Ajax (just set `<form method="post"...>` and add a `<input type="submit">`).

Comment: I have done this, it returned: Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
flag 2
fname First
lname Last
lnum 1
region VIC
Source
flag=2&region=VIC&lnum=1&fname=First&lname=Last

Comment: And is that the same thing that you are sending using Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Being relatively new to jQuery Ajax, Im not sure, but could this be a reason?

> data (Object, String): 
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not
>   already a string. It's appended to the
>   url for GET-requests.

Perhaps since this is not a GET, the data is 'falling off' ?

Comment: Nope, he's using data correctly. What the documentation means is that for all the other request types it's sent as the body, except that for GET it's appended to the URL.

Comment: It should work as the type is POST, I've tried it either way but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Matti - Thanks for the explanation / clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided nearly enough info on this question. How do you trigger the ajax request? If it happens inside a submit()-handler, you'll need to prevent the default behavior using event.preventDefault() or the request will be aborted by the default browser behavior. Are you sure you actually get inside the statement at all? This can be checked using Firebug to see if a request is even made, like many others have suggested.

So, try these simple things:

- In the event handler, use [event.preventDefault](http://jqapi.com/#p=event.preventDefault) to prevent default browser behavior
- Use Firebug to see if a request is being made to the server at all, and check the POST-data in the request (if one is sent)

Seeing as you're not really supplying enough info on how and where you call this code, I can only make guesses on what the problem is.

Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Hvae you confirmed the values you pass in AJAX have values? Try a simple alert and the var to see what is in it.

If the alert shows a value then change datatype to text and see if it passes data. DONT USE THIS FOR FINAL SOLUTION, just debugging